# TypeScript equivelent of Go's Defer statement

Tags: typescript

Does TypeScript have anything similar to Go's [Defer](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12) statement?

I am tired of writing cleanup code in multiple locations throughout a function. Looking for an easier solution.

I have done a quick Google, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Like `try ... finally`?

Comment: Yep, except I don't want to use a try catch block as they can be expensive.

Comment: `defer` is also expensive. Have your benchmarks indicated that `try...finally` has substantially more overhead than equivalent Go implementations using `defer`?

Answer (score 5):

Arguably the answer is no, but you have at least a couple of options:

1. As @bereal mentioned, you'd use a `try`/`finally` for that. Re `try`/`finally`, in a comment you said:

   > Yep, except I don't want to use a try catch block as they can be expensive.

   Not really. Throwing an `Error` is expensive (it's the creation that's expensive, filling in the stack info; the actual *throwing* of it doesn't cost much); entering a `try` block is not. And in JavaScript, you don't *have* to throw `Error` instances, you can throw anything; if you wanted to throw without the cost of filling in stack info, you could throw a non-`Error` (though I don't advocate it). Separately, `finally` blocks have *slight* overhead, but it happens I had to measure this in a couple of modern engines recently and it was truly amazingly trivial.
2. You can assign a function to a variable and then run it at the end of the function (or perhaps use an array if you want to do several). For the single cleanup, I'd expect it to be more expensive than `try`/`finally`. For multiple (which would otherwise require nested `try`/`finally` blocks), well, you'd have to find out.

FWIW, some examples:

A single cleanup in a `try`/`finally`:

```js
function example() {
    try {
        console.log("hello");
    } finally {
        console.log("world");
    }
}
example();
```

Multiple cleanup in a `try`/`finally`:

```js
function example() {
    try {
        console.log("my");
        try {
            console.log("dog");
        } finally {
            console.log("has");
        }
    } finally {
        console.log("fleas");
    }
}
example();
```

Single cleanup via assigning a function:

```js
function example() {
    let fn = null;
    fn = () => console.log("world");
    console.log("hello");
    if (fn) { // Allowing for the above to be conditional, even though
              // it isn't above
        fn();
    }
}
example();
```

Multiple cleanup in a `try`/`finally`:

```js
function example() {
    const cleanup = [];
    cleanup.push(() => console.log("has"));
    console.log("my");
    cleanup.push(() => console.log("fleas"));
    console.log("dog");
    cleanup.forEach(fn => fn());
}
example();
```

Or in the other order:

```js
function example() {
    const cleanup = [];
    cleanup.push(() => console.log("fleas"));
    console.log("my");
    cleanup.push(() => console.log("has"));
    console.log("dog");
    while (cleanup.length) {
        const fn = cleanup.pop();
        fn();
    }
}
example();
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope you can understand if I don't accept this answer, as I was looking for something that was purpose-built, but again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @daka - Well, that would be the *"Arguably the answer is no..."* part. :-) But absolutely, hold off for a few days in hopes someone knows something I don't.

Comment: I've used the last solution in several languages (including Go in places where `defer` wasn't practical due to when the cleanup had to run). I highly recommend it. It's extremely flexible.

Comment: `finally` can not use variables declared inside the `try` block.

Comment: @Huan - Indeed they can't. I'm not sure why the comment though? The answer doesn't suggest that they can.

Comment: I want to do this in TypeScript but can not found a solution for years: `try { const timer = setInterval(() => console.log('live'), 1000); /* some other code */ } finally { clearInterval(timer) }`. It seems it could be easy to do with the `defer` in Go.

Comment: @Huan - The main issue there isn't not being able to access `timer` in the `finally`, it's that the `finally` will run before the timer ever fires (unless this is in an `async` function and somewhere in `/* some other code */` you're using `await`). If it were just the scope thing, you could do this: `const timer = setInterval(() => console.log('live'), 1000); try { /* some other code */ } finally { clearInterval(timer) }` I don't know Go, but if you want to post a question about the TypeScript thing that's giving you trouble, I'd be happy to try to help. :-)

Comment: Glad to know that you are happy to discuss this! I'll write a PoC to demonstrate what I want...

Answer (score 0):

What I want is a clearer way to do a `defer` job as same as Go in TypeScript:

```
class Test {

  @Defer()
  async test () {
    const timer = setInterval(() => console.log('interval'), 1000)
    defer.call(this, () => clearInterval(timer))
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500))
  }

}

const t = new Test()
t.test()
  .catch(console.error)
```

In the above code, we define a `timer` to output `interval` for every 1 second, and define a `defer` to clear interval when out of this function scope (the same as Go).

When running it, the `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500)` will wait 1.5 seconds, which will output one line of `interval` output, then the program exit.

```
$ ts-node src/defer.ts 
interval
$
```

The following code example is the full code which can be run directly by copy/paste with TypeScript 4.4:

```
const DEFER_SYMBOL = Symbol('defer')

type Callback = (err?: Error) => void

interface DeferizedThis {
  [DEFER_SYMBOL]?: Callback[],
}

function Defer () {
  return function callMethodDecorator (
    _target      : any,
    _propertyKey : string,
    descriptor   : PropertyDescriptor,
  ): PropertyDescriptor {

    const oldValue = descriptor.value

    async function deferizedMethod (
      this: DeferizedThis,
      ...args: any[]
    ) {
      try {
        const ret = await oldValue.apply(this, args)
        return ret
      } finally {
        if (this[DEFER_SYMBOL]) {
          const deferCallbacks = this[DEFER_SYMBOL]

          while (true) {
            const fn = deferCallbacks?.pop()
            if (!fn) { break }
            try { fn() } catch (e) { console.error(e) }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    descriptor.value = deferizedMethod
    return descriptor
  }
}

function defer (
  this: any,
  cb: Callback,
): void {
  if (this[DEFER_SYMBOL]) {
    this[DEFER_SYMBOL]!.push(cb)
  } else {
    this[DEFER_SYMBOL] = [cb]
  }
}

class Test {

  @Defer()
  async test () {
    const timer = setInterval(() => console.log('interval'), 1000)
    defer.call(this, () => clearInterval(timer))
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500))
  }

}

const t = new Test()
t.test()
  .catch(console.error)
```

If you have read the above code, it's clearly a buggy PoC and definitely can not be used in production.

I'd like to discuss if we have any good ways to achieve this in TypeScript, by following this decorator way, or any direction else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, From original T.J. Crowder(@t-j-crowder) Response.

Defer by referencing variables in the finally block of a try/catch block

```js
function example() {
    const defers = [];
    try {
        var xx = "Firts";
        defers.push(((text) => () => console.log(text))(xx));
        xx = "No Firts";
        var yy = "Last";
        defers.push(((text) => () => console.log(text))(yy));
        yy = "No Last"
        const timer = setInterval(() => console.log('live'), 1000);
        defers.push(((t) => () => clearInterval(t))(timer));
    } finally {
        while (defers.length) {
            const fn = defers.pop();
            fn();
        }
    }
}
example();
```